# HashMap with MySQL

Tags: java, file

I have faced a scenario: the task was to read a file which contains 3 Millions IP Address.

There is a MySQL table which contains `Id,PrimaryIP`, `PrimaryIP` can by multiple IP separated by `#`, moreover that `PrimaryIP` can also contain CIDR IP.

In totally, there are 8000 records, each record with multiple IP and CIDR IP.

Now, my task was to read that file, check it against with database and write the matching `IP,ID` to a file.

Initially, when I run my program, my program failed because:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have increased it by 3GB. It was still failing, then I later split the file into 6 subfiles, as 0.5 million each.

To find CIDR IP List, I have used Apache SubnetUtils.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT id,PrimaryIP from IPTable where PrimaryIP != '' limit 100000;";
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        File oFile = new File("output.txt");
        System.out.println(new Date());
        try{
            List<String> fileData = FileUtils.readLines(new File("input.txt"));
            System.out.println("File Data Size : "+fileData.size());

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?user=root&password=pwd");

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

            System.out.println("Started with MySQL Querying");

            Map<String, Integer> primaryIPIDMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                primaryIPIDMap.clear();
                int recordID = resultSet.getInt(1);

                if (resultSet.getString(2).contains("#")) {
                    String primaryIP[] = resultSet.getString(2).split("#");

                    for (int i = 0; i < primaryIP.length; i++) {
                        if (primaryIP[i].contains("/")) {
                            String allIP[] = getAllIP(primaryIP[i]);
                            for (int allIPi = 0; allIPi < allIP.length; allIPi++) {
                                primaryIPIDMap.put(allIP[allIPi].intern(), recordID);
                            }
                        } else {
                            primaryIPIDMap.put(primaryIP[i].intern(), recordID);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    primaryIPIDMap.put(resultSet.getString(2).intern(), recordID);
                }

                Iterator entries = fileData.iterator();
                while (entries.hasNext()) {
                    String t = (String) entries.next();
                    if (primaryIPIDMap.containsKey(t)) {
                        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(oFile, recordID + "," + t);
                    }
                }
                primaryIPIDMap.clear();
            }

            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement != null)
                    statement.close();
            } catch (Exception se2) {
            }
            try {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.close();
            } catch (Exception se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Finished");
        System.out.println("End Time : "+new Date());
    }

    private static String[] getAllIP(String ip) {
        return new SubnetUtils(ip).getInfo().getAllAddresses();
    }
```

Can someone tell me the best practice for solving this? Today it just has 3 million, but tomorrow it may be 5 million. I can't keep on creating subfiles.

Comment: does the code work properly?

Comment: What is maximum size of primaryIPIDMap? It seems like you are trying to use memory as itermediate storage for whole data set, instead of writing result out immediately.

Comment: Is it O(n^2) or its just me?

Comment: @MannyMeng It seems to be about a memory optimization, which is normally on-topic here.

Comment: @Basilevs "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" and "Can someone tell me the best practice for solving this? Today it just has 3 million, but tomorrow it may be 5 million. I can't keep on creating subfiles." (perhaps you shouldn't pay too much attention to me though, I'm sick!)

Comment: Now that I think about it more, we definitely can say that eliminating a map of 3*10^6 items that we don't need is indeed memory optimization.

Comment: It is possible to set the Java heap/stack size to whatever size you need as a JVM argument.

Comment: @MannyMeng yes, the code works properly.

Comment: @Ryan i guess you can set, but it is not the best practice to change the heap/size based on the code or project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions.

I fixed the problem using

- Reading the input file `line-by-line`
- I didn't change MySQL Table structure because it has a dependency in many places and table was `not designed` by me.

Comment: On the stackexchange network one usually marks the answer as accepted which helped the most, unless there isn't one. In this case seems like the line-by-line suggestion put you in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

You have 'too much' data to keep in resident memory.  There are a number of things you can do to smoothe this out, but they will take a bit more effort than rearranging code.

## Read input line per line

Right now, the algorithm looks a little like this:

*For each record in the database, search the input file for a match and write that match to output.*

Since the database is the indexed one, and the input file (probably) isn't, we'll save time going at it the other way:

*For each line in the input file, find the matching record(s) and write them to output.*

This will let us read the input file line per line, just once, using java.io.BufferedReader, which will save you from having to slice your files into bits.  We will have to hit the database (or a in-memory version that you keep) more often, but they're built for this, and may cache some things:

```
try ( Connection connection = /*...*/ ;
      Statement statement = /*...*/ ) {
    try ( BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(input, charset);
          BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(output, charset) ) {
        for ( String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine() ) {
            // 1. parse line
            // 2. query database
            // 3. write out result
        }
    }
}
```

As a bonus, this would mean you can use your program as a 'text utility' reading from standard input and writing to standard output, where compression could make you save drastically save on disk churning:

```
zcat input.gz | java pkg.MyAwesomeFilter | gzip > output.gz
```

## Database Schema

> There is a MySQL table which contains Id,PrimaryIP, PrimaryIP can by multiple IP separated by #, moreover that PrimaryIP can also contain CIDR IP.

Remove the packing by '#'; let the database worry about compressing results if it really has to.  Split out the IP addresses so that you have a clean Id x PrimaryIP M:N relation.  This will make querying on PrimaryIP easier.

The CIDR will be a bit harder to fit into this.  See if you can make an extra table `IPRange` that stores IP ranges per minimum and maximum possible IP address.  For instance, 10.0.0.0/8 would be 10.0.0.0 -> 10.255.255.255 .  This way, you won't have to store every possible address.

Now that you have a more direct schema, you can make the database do some of the heavy lifting:

```sql
(select `id` from iptable where primaryIP = ?)
union
(select `id` from iprange where ? between minIP and maxIP)
```

For range queries to work, however, you will need to change the way you store the IP addresses so that they can be quickly compared.  You could either make them string-comparable through making each segment always 3 chars long, or you could parse the address as a number and use that:

```
10.0.0.0     -> 010 000 000 000
192.168.1.11 -> 192 168 001 011
```

(I *think* this should also work for IPv6.)

## Other remarks

Consider using try-with-resources (see example above) for your database connections and file streams; it really cleans up I/O code.

You don't seem to specify the character encodings of your input and output.  Considering the domain, I doubt you'll run into serious trouble, but it may be useful to decide on an encoding like, say, UTF-8.

I doubt String.intern() will help you much.  Interning helps to reduce the number of copies in memory, true, but since you use them as hash keys, you'll discard duplicates anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on reading the file first, then I suggest not reading the file all at once (the FileUtil.readLines call), but instead using a buffered reader to read a few lines at a time, until your done.

Seems like a better approach would be to load the 8000 records out of MySQL, then iterate over each line in the file and see if it matches one of the rows in MySQL.

An even better approach would be to put your "file" into the DB, and just do a join, letting MySQL handle it.

Answer (score 2):

A side note:

> There is a MySQL table which contains Id,PrimaryIP, PrimaryIP can by multiple IP separated by #

Wrong. Normally, a database should be normalized. There's a sequence of [Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) and the very first rule says

> The domain of each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain.

Sure, to every rule, there's an exception, but for every exception there should be a good reason. For breaking the most fundamental rule there should be a very fundamental reason.

---

> Can someone tell me the best practice for solving this? Today it just has 3 million, but tomorrow it may be 5 million. I can't keep on creating subfiles.

You can, but this would mean writing a script or whatever and you just don't need it. Simply replace

```
List<String> fileData = FileUtils.readLines(new File("input.txt"));
```

by a loop, read a part of the file and process as you did. This solves this problem, the others wrote enough about the code.

---

A database is a beast which gets fed with a piece of date and it itself does the processing. All you usually need is some parsing and converting the food in a format digestible by the beast (here just line parsing). No own lookups needed. What you do looks like the exact opposite (sorry, too lazy to work me though it all).